# Understanding escape sequence for literal bracketing marks

Tags: awk

I am constructing a pattern in awk that handles literal bracketing marks.  How do escape sequences work for use in a dynamic regex?

I thought to first escape the `[`, then escape the `\`  with

```
ptrn = "\\\]"
```

But then one can have the following

```
ptrn = "\\]"
```

The first backslash is used to escape the second backslash, which is itself
used to escape the "[".  And so on for the other bracketing marks `[`, `{`, `(`, `}`, `)`.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this ?

```
 mawk '
 function ___(__,_) { 
     return \
     substr(_ = (_ = "\\")_, 
       gsub("[[-`!-/:-@{-~]", "[&]",__), 
      -gsub( "[" (_) "^]", (_) "&",__))__ 
 }
 ($++NF = ___($!_))^_' OFS='\f\f\r\t'
```

.

```
[^\t[:digit:]\n]|[A-Zz-a]

[[][\^][\\]t[[][:]digit[:][]][\\]n[]][|][[]A[-]Zz[-]a[]]
```

> ---

```
\\f

[\\][\\]f
```

by forcing any existing backslash into its own "cage" (`\` —> `[\\]`), it silos their effects and prevents any regex engine from attempting to associate those backslashes with anything immediately after them, thus ensuring only literal backslashes are being matched

Comment: The result is too complicated for people to actually understand.  I wonder how I can, provided some dynamic regex, determine what awk would actually see.

Comment: @Dilna : how is it complicated ? it's literally only 2 calls to `gsub(…)` …. u think `\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\[` is any better ? You can make it clean, and escape literal `]` as `[]]`, or you can fuss about how many trillion layers of backslashes you need.